# spaCy phrasematcher failing some cases though POS tags the same

Tags: python, spacy

The spaCy PhraseMatcher (using the LEMMA attribute) is only working on some of my sentences, but its failure seems entirely random. I have a minimal working example below, trying to extract the term 'colorful':

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe("lemmatizer")

from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LEMMA")
matcher.add('colorful', nlp('colorful'))

text1 = "this is the most colorful of the four pieces"
text2 = "colorful and bold"

text1_matches = matcher(nlp(text1))
text2_matches = matcher(nlp(text2))

# These are the results that I get
text1_matches = [(9306951126003165228, 4, 5)]
text2_matches = []
```

Why is the PhraseMatcher finding the first example but not the second? In both, the 'colorful' POS tag is `(ADJ)` and the lemma is `'colorful'`. What else could possibly be different between the sentences that would cause the PhraseMatcher to find one but not the other?

What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of spaCy are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3, which to my understanding is the most current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to update spaCy:

`pip install spacy --upgrade`

Download your model:

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

And use this code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LEMMA")
matcher.add('colorful', [nlp('colorful')])

text1 = "this is the most colorful of the four pieces"
text2 = "colorful and bold"

text1_matches = matcher(nlp(text1))
text2_matches = matcher(nlp(text2))
```

Comment: Wow, removing the add_pipe line fixed it!! Thanks so much!